# 100times performance slowdown when using javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket

Tags: java, apache, sockets, ssl, encryption

In my main project I am transferring large amount of binary data between server and client.

The server is a odroid xu4 with ArchLinux.
The client is currently a MacbookPro. However the problem occurs also when using Windows on HP.

It took me some while until I found out that the **javax.net.ssl encryption** causes a huge performance decrease when it comes to sending data over a TCP java socket.

Therefore I created a testing environment - consisting of the client, server and a router - and a project in IntelliJ for measuring performance stats.

The test measures only the time needed for transferring a **5-megabyte** file from the client to the server. The time needed to establish the connection - SSL-Handshake - takes about 2 seconds, which is still ok and not a problem. However stoping the time for transferring the file lead to the following results:

Socket without encryption: **200ms**.

Using a simple **SCP**-command: **200ms**.

Socket with **TLSv1** encryption: **22 seconds**.

In the following I show the client and the server class, which I used for testing: **Server**

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class Server {

    protected final static String keyPath = "/home/*****************/trust/keystore.keystore";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyPath), "*****************".toCharArray());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "*****************".toCharArray());

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory factory = context.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(00000);

        serverSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"SSLv3", "TLSv1"});

        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(1024*1024*5);
        socket.setSendBufferSize(1024*1024*5);

        socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent handshakeCompletedEvent) {
                System.out.println("CipherSuite: " + handshakeCompletedEvent.getCipherSuite());
                System.out.println("CipherSuite: " + handshakeCompletedEvent.getSession().getCipherSuite());
                System.out.println("Protocol: " + handshakeCompletedEvent.getSession().getProtocol());
            }
        });

        int size = 16*1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[size];
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

        int count;
        long sum = 0;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) > -1) {
            sum += count;
        }
        System.out.println();
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Size:\t" + size + "\tTime:\t" + elapsedTime + "\tRead:\t" + sum/1024/1024);
    }
}
```

The **Client** Class:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", Client.class.getResource("truststore.truststore").getPath());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "*****************");

        SSLSocketFactory factory =  (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.***.***");
        //Socket socket = new Socket(address, 55552);
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(address, 55552);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(1024*1024*5);
        socket.setSendBufferSize(1024*1024*5);

        for(String chipher : socket.getEnabledCipherSuites()) System.out.println(chipher);

        String path = "/Users/harald/Desktop/SpeedTest/file5M.img";
        File file = new File(path);

        int size = 16*1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[size];
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

        int count;
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) > -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Time:\t" + elapsedTime + "\tRead:\t");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

As visible I set SendBufferSize and ReceiveBufferSize to 5MB. This gave me the hint, that the time needed for sending and encrypting the 5MB file is very dependent on the cpu of the client and the server. The client needs about **9 seconds** for encrypting the data and putting it into the socket.
The client has a **3,3 GHz Intel Core i7**.

The odroid single-board computer has of course a weaker cpu and needs therefore the 22 seconds for receiving and encrypting the files. The Linux command **Top** showed me that one core has always **100% workload** when transferring the files.

---

The conclusion is that there are maybe some bad implementation problems in the javax.net.ssl library or I have something forgotten in my code, which lead to this problem.

First solution could be using **org.apache.conn.ssl** instead of javax.net.
However I am currently thinking there is only a client side implementation for SSLSockets. If there would also be a opportunity to create a SSLServerSocket I would not need to use javax anymore. However the performance was not testet with apaches sslsockets.

Second solution could be using another cipher suite, which has less cpu workload. But I don't think this would be enough.

I really hope somebody can help me with this problem or knows how to write a bug report, if it is a implementation problem.

I am looking forward Harald.

Comment: It can be hard to diagnose the problem, but I would first avoid messing with the receive and send buffers, and not change the tcpNoDelay settings. Normal buffer sizes and nagle settings should work just fine for sending files. My guess is that the ciphersuite chosen is particularly poor for the server. You might experiment with something like POLY1305-CHACHA ciphersuite which might have superior performance.

Comment: Do you know how to set these kind of ciphersuites? Than I could test it again :)

Comment: Actually Oracle Java probably does not support these ciphersuites yet. You might try and RC4 ciphersuite, though RC4 is not considered secure enough and has been deprecated. At the very least you can measure the performance with RC4 and see if its any better. The ciphersuites are list [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider). EDIT. Actually, the CHA-CHA ciphersuites are apparentky available in the bctls provider

Comment: Did you manage to increase the buffer size?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem lies deeper. It is all dependent on the underlying implementation of javas encryption and the missing usage of hardware acceleration. I reprogrammed everything in C and used OpenSSL and I achieved same speeds as with SCP.